# Adding h4 in Woocommerce attribute and custom field list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am displaying several product attributes and custom meta fields on the single product page with this code I got [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67568391/adding-meta-fields-to-attribute-list-on-woocommerce-single-product-page):

```
function action_woocommerce_single_product_summary() {
global $product;

$attributes_names = array( 'Brand', 'Color', 'Size' );

$attributes_data  = array();

foreach ( $attributes_names as $attribute_name ) {
    if ( $value = $product->get_attribute($attribute_name) ) {
        $attributes_data[] = $attribute_name . ': ' . $value;
    }       
}

// NOT empty
if ( ! empty($attributes_data) ) {
    echo '<h4>' . __( 'Details', 'woocommerce' ) . '</h4><ul><li>' . implode( '</li><li>', $attributes_data );
}

// Get meta
$sn = $product->get_meta( 'Serial_Number' );    
$mpn = $product->get_meta( 'MPN' );

// NOT empty
if ( ! empty ( $sn ) ) {
    echo '<li>' . __( 'My label 1: ', 'woocommerce' ) . $sn . '</li>';
}

// NOT empty
if ( ! empty ( $mpn ) ) {
    echo '<li>' . __( 'My label 2: ', 'woocommerce' ) . $mpn . '</li>';
}

echo '</ul>';
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'action_woocommerce_single_product_summary', 36, 0 );
```

My problem is that the h4 ('Details') and the starting ul are only displayed when there are attributes. When there are only custom fields set for a product, the h4 and the starting ul for the list are not displayed. How can I always show the h4 and the starting

  whenever either an attribute or a custom field is set for a product?

EDIT to clarify: There are 3 possible product types:

products that have attributes AND custom fields

products that ONLY have an attribute OR custom field

products that neither have an attribute or custom field

For the first type of products, it should be displayed for example:

```
<h4>Details</h4>
<ul>
<li>Brand: ...</li>
<li>MPN: ...</li>
</ul>
```

For the second type of products an example would be:

```
<h4>Details</h4>
<ul>
<li>MPN: ...</li>
</ul>
```

and for the last type of products NOTHING should be displayed at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to set that up, you could do that using either `if/else` statement or a `ternary` operator. For example you could do something like this:

```php
// Using "if/else" method 

if ( ! empty($attributes_data) ) {

    echo '<h4>' . __( 'Details', 'woocommerce' ) . '</h4><ul><li>' . implode( '</li><li>', $attributes_data );

}else{

    // if it's empty you could output a placeholder text OR a any value you could get from woocommerce

    echo '<h4>' . __( 'Details', 'woocommerce' ) . '</h4><span>' . {YOUR VALUE OR PLACEHOLDER TEXT AS A FALLBACK} . '</span>';

}
```

Or you could use the `ternary` operator like so:

```php
echo ( ! empty($attributes_data) ) ? '<h4>' . __( 'Details', 'woocommerce' ) . '</h4><ul><li>' . implode( '</li><li>', $attributes_data ) : '<h4>' . __( 'Details', 'woocommerce' ) . '</h4><span>' . {YOUR VALUE OR PLACEHOLDER TEXT AS A FALLBACK} . '</span>';
```

---

**EDIT**

Assuming that `Serial_Number` and `MPN` are your custom fields, you could set your `if` condition like this:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'action_woocommerce_single_product_summary', 36, 0 );

function action_woocommerce_single_product_summary()
{
  global $product;
  
  $attributes_names = array( 'Brand', 'Color', 'Size' );
  
  $attributes_data  = array();
  
  foreach ( $attributes_names as $attribute_name ) {
      if ( $value = $product->get_attribute($attribute_name) ) {
          $attributes_data[] = $attribute_name . ': ' . $value;
      }       
  }

  $sn = $product->get_meta( 'Serial_Number' );    
  $mpn = $product->get_meta( 'MPN' );

  // Assuming that 'Serial_Number' and 'MPN' are your custom fields
  
  if(! empty($attributes_data) && ! empty ( $sn ) && ! empty ( $mpn )){

    echo '<h4>' . __( 'Details', 'woocommerce' ) . '</h4><ul><li>' . implode( '</li><li>', $attributes_data );
    echo '<li>' . __( 'My label 1: ', 'woocommerce' ) . $sn . '</li>';
    echo '<li>' . __( 'My label 2: ', 'woocommerce' ) . $mpn . '</li>';
    echo '</ul>';

  }elseif(! empty($attributes_data) || ! empty ( $sn ) || ! empty ( $mpn )){

    echo ( ! empty($attributes_data)) ? '<h4>' . __( 'Details', 'woocommerce' ) . '</h4><ul><li>' . implode( '</li><li>', $attributes_data ): '<h4>' . __( 'Details', 'woocommerce' ) . '</h4><ul>';
    echo (! empty ( $sn )) ? '<li>' . __( 'My label 1: ', 'woocommerce' ) . $sn . '</li>' : "";
    echo (! empty ( $mpn )) ? '<li>' . __( 'My label 2: ', 'woocommerce' ) . $mpn . '</li>': "";
    echo '</ul>';

  }else{

    echo '<h4>' . __( 'Details', 'woocommerce' ) . '</h4><p>Looks like there is no extra info on this product!</p>'; 

  }
}
```

Let me know if that is what you're looking for!

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work in my case. I have producs that have both, attributes AND custom fields, and in this case bth should be displayed in the ul, then there are products which only have either attributes OR custom fields, and then these should be displayed with the heading on top, and then there are products without attributes or custom fields, and in that case NOTHING should be displayed at all.

Comment: Ok, you could use the same logic that i suggested. If you need a detailed answer please edit your question with all of the details and scenarios, so that i could write a code that exactly suite your needs!

Comment: Tank you @Ruvee, but now for products that have both attributes and custom fields, the whole block "Details" including all the attributes and custom fields is displayed twice.