# Is there any wordpress function to display only particular custom attribute of product on every product card or product overview page?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode

I need to display a custom attribute on very product card in wordpress website.
I have used a php function which is :

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title',function(){
    
    global $product;
    
    echo wc_display_product_attributes( $product );
    
    

} );
```

This code enable or display all attributes, but I need only to show a specific attribute.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get product custom attributes to display them in WooCommerce product loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64389872/get-product-custom-attributes-to-display-them-in-woocommerce-product-loop)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the get_product_attributes() function of Woocommerce. This will return an array of product attributes, where each attribute is an object that contains the name and value of the attribute.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'display_custom_attribute' );
function display_custom_attribute() {
    global $product;

    // Getting all product attributes
    $attributes = $product->get_attributes();

    // confirming if the attribute you want to display exist
    // don't forget to replace your custom attribute name
    if ( isset( $attributes['your_custom_attribute_name'] ) ) {
        // retrieving the attribute object
        $attribute = $attributes['your_custom_attribute_name'];

        // then retrieving the attribute name and value
        $attribute_name = $attribute->get_name();
        $attribute_value = $attribute->get_options()[0]; // This is assuming that the attribute has only one value

        // finally echoing the attribute name and value
        echo '<div class="custom-attribute">';
        echo '<span class="attribute-name">' . $attribute_name . ': </span>';
        echo '<span class="attribute-value">' . $attribute_value . '</span>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```